# django automatic survey popup after some times of session

Tags: python, django, popup, survey

I want to show survey pop up automatically in my webpage sometimes after web session is started, How can I implement this using Django?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there not plenty of examples on the web or SO?

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to Django, you can achieve it with client side technologies.

One possible option is using setTimeout function in javascript. You can use it like so:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // this piece of code will be executed after 10 seconds
}, 10000 // miliseconds)
```

Of course, this would be lost / reset after user refreshes the page. If you want to show the popup after user spends some amount of time in your website across sessions, you can combine this method with some persistense, either using **localStorage** of the browser, or using django's session storage.

Comment: Thank You, I used LocalStorage to retain across pages. It Worked!!